# @ngrx/effects BehaviourSubject giving last value to subscribers

Tags: javascript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

Something I noticed the other day. I was subscribing to the `Actions` stream inside `@ngrx/effects`. I noticed (an issue for me) where a component, which subscribes to `Actions` late, receives the last dispatched action. This I can see is because the dispatcher inside `@ngrx/store` is a `BehaviourSubject` and quoting the RxJS docs:

> **Rx.BehaviorSubject class**
>
> Represents a value that changes over time. Observers can subscribe to the subject to receive the last (or initial) value and all subsequent notifications.

Unfortunately, I'd like to subscribe to the actions stream without retrieving the last value. It creates problems for me like showing error messages when a user returns to a page.

The difference between `BehaviorSubject` and `Subject` (which does it the way I'd like) is demo'd here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwgype

Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the first value with the 'skip' operator:

```
someBehaviorSubject.skip(1)
```

Comment: Agreed, however when I dispatch an actual action to display an error message the first time, I'll end up skipping it. :-/

Comment: If it is a behavior subject then it always has an initial value (undefined value if not provided), and you will skip this initial value only. If you keep your subscription open you will get the next value on update.

Comment: Just make sure the `skip` is before the `ofType` that's usually used to filter actions.

Comment: Yep, in your case it's better be before any filtering

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it is skipping the action I'm trying to catch.  Pressing the submit button and dispatching the action a second time displays the error message as expected

Comment: @ZahiC maybe I didn't do the skip before `ofType`. I'll check this.

Comment: So I've since tried this, it works apart from I cannot use `ofType` after `skip(1)` ... Since `ofType` is not part of RxJS. I guess I could use filter, just not a huge fan of this approach.